# Prove if $p\nmid a$ then $a^{p^2}\equiv a^p\bmod p^2$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Prove if $p\nmid a$ then $a^{p^2}\equiv a^p\bmod p^2$.

I tried to use Fermat's little theorem and I got $a^{p^2}\equiv a\bmod p^2$ but I don't know how to prove the main result.

Answer (score 3):

Euler's theorem, a generalisation of Fermat's little theorem, gives us that
$$a^{\varphi(p^2)}\equiv1\bmod p^2$$
But $\varphi(p^2)=p(p-1)$, so
$$a^{p(p-1)}\equiv1\bmod p^2$$
Multiply by $a^p$ to establish the desired result:
$$a^{p^2}\equiv a^p\bmod p^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\phi(p^2)= p^2-p$$ thus $$a^{p^2} = a^{\phi(p)}\cdot a^p \equiv a^p (mod \hspace{0,3cm} p^2).$$